# How to get hgk working on RedHat Linux?

Tags: rhel, configuration, mercurial

I plan to get hgk to work.However, no matter how I configure the redhat linux, it still does not have any response. Here is information for my machine.

1. RedHat 5.3
2. Mercurial 1.8.1-1
3. I installed mercurial-hgk_1.8.1-1.elf5.x86_64.rpm by rpm and it generated a
   directory `/usr/bin/hgk`

When I typed `hg help`, it didn't show the view..etc the additional extensions commands. Here are things I have tried.

1. Manually created a `.hgrc` file at home directory and put the configuration as

   ```
   [extensions]
   hgk = /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/hgext/hgk.py
   ```
2. Add all these configurations at hgrc files of my local repository such at

   ```
   /home/Cassie/CassieRepo/Repo1/.hg
   ```

Nothing happened — When I typed `hg help` or `hg view`, the mercurial still does not recognize the additional `view` command.

I typed `hgk`. Here are the outputs.

```
Error in startup script: can't read "env(HG)": no such variable
    while executing
"exec $env(HG) debug-config"
    (procedure "getconfig" line 4)
    invoked from within
"getconfig"
    invoked from within
"array set config [getconfig]"
    (file "/usr/bin/hgk" line 4054)
```

I typed `rpm -ql mercurial | grep bin` and here are the outputs.

```
/usr/bin/hg
```

I typed `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path` and here are the outputs.

```
['', '/usr/lib64/python24.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.4', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages']
```

Comment: Please add output of `type hg`.  `rpm -ql mercurial | grep bin`.  `type python`.  `python -c 'import sys; print sys.path'`.  `type hgk`.  And (2) is wrong: `[hgk]path` should name the `hgk` TCL script, not the Python module.  What happens if you just try running `hgk`?

Comment: "it generated a directory /usr/bin/hgk"?  `/usr/bin/hgk` should be a file I think.

Comment: Use tortoisehg. hgk is depreciated. If you are using RHEL 5.3, please say so. Redhat 5.3 would refer to Red Hat's original distribution, which is dead for many years now.

Comment: @Mikel, would you please see the added part of my questions? For Faheem, I did try to install the tortoiseHg. However, I encountered problem as [here](http://superuser.com/questions/420722/tortoisehg-installation-error-on-redhat-5-3). If you have any surggestion, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: In addition, my Redhat 5.3 is not personal use linux.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue. Adding the following lines to `~/.hgrc` resolved the issue for me:

```
[extensions]
hgext.hgk =
```

Then `hgk` was available using the `hg view` command.

Comment: equals to what ?